# how to disable swap in ion-slide-box in Ionic Framework

Tags: ionic-framework

i want to disable swap in ion-slide-box so i added this

active-slide="slidestop($index)"

in ionic-slide-box as you can see below

```
<ion-slide-box show-pager="false" ng-repeat="test in demoQuiz" active-slide="slidestop($index)">
```

and added this in controller.js

```
 $scope.slidestop = function(index) {
            $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.enableSlide(false);
        }
```

but i'm getting this error:(

```
Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'slidestop($index)' used with directive 'ionSlideBox' is non-assignable!
```

although this code working fine:)

Answer (score 0):

If you carefully see ionic Docs, you will find that

> **active-slide** is an expression, which represents the Model to bind the current slide to.

You have written a method invocation inside the active-slide attribute, without returning anything from the method.

You can rewrite the stuff like this :

```
    <ion-slide-box show-pager="false" ng-repeat="test in demoQuiz" active-slide="activeSlide">
```

Then, Inside your controller, you can write

```
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.stop()
```

This will stop ionic slide box until and unless you explicitly change the slides.

More Details [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicSlideBoxDelegate/)

Comment: what is not working, is the slide box still sliding Automatically ??